# Error in on_message when i try to add reaction python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make bot react to every message in specific channel, this is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  channel = bot.get_channel(837590298435649537)
  if message in channel:
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

And this is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 15, in on_message
    if message in channel:
TypeError: argument of type 'TextChannel' is not iterable
```

I don't know what's wrong, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `message in channel` you would have to use

```py
if message.channel == channel:
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
```